# What is the full differential of Van der Waal equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Van der Waal equation: $$(p + aN^2/V^2)(V - bN) = nRT. $$

I am trying to get $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T})_{V}$ and $(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{p}$.

what I have done:

$(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T})_{V} = \frac{NR}{V - bN}$

$(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} = \frac{NR}{p + \frac{aN^2}{V^2}}$

I feel like I did something wrong, but I cannot find the mistake, please help. I ask this question is because I was told that the hint is use full differential  to get the partial derivative of V, but I did not use it.

Comment: What do you mean by full differential.

Comment: with respect to V

Comment: differentiating means you need two variables, are you asking for $dP/dT$.

Comment: Actually I was trying to get $(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_{V}$ and $(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P}$, and what I got are $(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_{V} = \frac{NR}{V - bN}$, $(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} = \frac{NR}{P + \frac{aN^2}{V^2}}$. I was told that the hint is take the full differential of Van der Waal equation, then I got so confused.

Comment: Okay ! I got it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first write Van der Waal's equation

$$\left(P+\frac{aN^2}{V^2}\right)(V-bN)=nRT$$

which  we can reduce to

$$PV-bNP+\frac{aN^2}{V}-\frac{abN^3}{V^2}=nRT$$
taking the total derivative
$$d(PV)-bNdP-\frac{aN^2}{V^2}dV+\frac{2abN^3}{V^3}dV=nRdT$$
or
$$PdV+VdP-bNdP-\frac{aN^2}{V^2}dV+\frac{2abN^3}{V^3}dV=nRdT$$
or
$$\left( P-\frac{aN^2}{V^2}+\frac{2abN^3}{V^3}\right)dV+(V-bN)dP=nRdT$$

So Everything is done here. One more thing is to note that for any function $f(x,y)$
.
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

Now To compute $\partial P/\partial T$ We will write total derivative of $P$ in term of $dT$ and $dV$.

$$dP=\frac{1}{bN-V}\left[\left( P-\frac{aN^2}{V^2}+\frac{2abN^3}{V^3}\right)dV+nRdT\right]$$

compare it with
$$dP=\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}dV+\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}dT$$

comparing both equation will give
$$\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=\frac{nR}{bN-V}$$

In a similar procedure, you can find other partial  derivative.

Cheers!

---

Note that they may be a mistake but the method will remain same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what exactly you're looking for when you refer to full differential but my interpretation is that you mean you're trying to find the exact differential. I'm going to completely ignore that since I don't have enough information about the question at hand and just address your partial derivative problems. The $(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_V$ is correct except that $N$ should be $n$ but not the second one. It appears you didn't apply the product rule when taking derivatives according to $T$. Properly applying the product rule to the problem, we get
$$  -  \frac{2aN^2}{V^3}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}(V - bN) + \left(p + \frac{aN^2}{V^2}\right)\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}  = nR $$
Solving for $ \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}$,
$$ \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P} = \frac{nR}{p + \frac{aN^2}{V^2} -  \frac{2aN^2}{V^3} (V - bN)    }  \\ = \frac{nR}{p - \frac{aN^2}{V^2} +  \frac{2abN^3}{V^3}    }$$
You didn't mention in the post but it's common usage of $n$ to refer to the number density , given  by $N/V$ in which case,
$$ \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P} = \frac{nR}{p - an^2 +  2abn^3   } $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!